# Constrained constructor in class hierarchy, C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, abstract-class, subclass

Let's say I have two classes, abstract classes.

```
class A {
//code...
};
class B {
public:
  B(A *x);
};
```

And I extend both classes as follows:

```
class A1 : public A {
};
class A2 : public A {
};

class B1 : public B {
public:
   B1(A1 *x);
};
class B2 : public B {
   B2(A2 *x);
};
```

This means that a `B1` object can be instantiated using only a `A1`, while `B2` necessarily need a `B1` object right? There's no chance I could mix things, using A2 for instantiate B1 for example. This is because the classes `A,B` are abstracts. What about if `A,B` are not abstract? does it change something?

Comment: `B2` needs a pointer to an `A2`.

Comment: You can make their ctor taking `A*` as parameter, then you can use `A1` or `A2` to construct them.

Comment: What exactly makes you suspect B1 can be instantiated with an A2? Why with A2 and not Foo, Bar, int(int) or std::string?

Comment: "*What about if `A`, `B` are not abstract?*" Why don't you try and see?

Answer (score 1):

> What about if A,B are not abstract? does it change something?

No. The main impact of this is that the user can construct an `A` directly. If `B`'s constructor is public, they will also be able to instantiate a `B` from that `A` object.

However, they won't be able to instantiate either `B1` or `B2` from that `A`. Since their constructors take an `A1` and `A2` respectively, which are subclasses of `A`, you cannot instantiate them from an `A` or from the wrong subclass of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

> This means that a B1 object can be instantiated using only a A1

Sort of. They must pass a `A1` pointer to the constructor, but they don't need an instance of `A1`, because they could simply pass a `nullptr`.

> while B2 necessarily need a B1 object right?

No. `B2` needs an `A2` and `B1` doesn't inherit `A2`.

> here's no chance I could mix things, using A2 for instantiate B1 for example.

There is no chance indeed. `A2*` is not convertible to `A1*`.

> This is because the classes A,B are abstracts. What about if A,B are not abstract?

Whether they are abstract has no effect on whether `B1` can be instantiated with an `A2`.